# Get formData appended data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a new FormData then added caption as key.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('caption','abc');
```

How do I get abc from it? I tried using .get but it's [not supported in mobile chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get).

```
formData.get('caption'); // this will not work by default in chrome.
```

Is there anywhere I can get caption value?

Comment: you get the values from the server once you submit, not from js. JS is not an amnesiac, how can it not know what you just told it? (aka don't use FormData to store locally).

Answer (score 1):

By default Chome does not support the `.get()` method, you can enable that functionality by activating an flag.

Chrome default support for method append.

Methods which chrome does't support in default behavior : `delete`, `get`, `getAll`, `has`, and `set`.

For activating flags in Chrome you can go to the following link:

[chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-webkit-features](http://chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-webkit-features)